# How to Create a Function to Receive Keyboard Input in JavaScript (nodejs) Without HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, user-input

I'm trying to get an input from the keyboard by calling a function that uses the built-in readline module, but it seems that the loop "doesn't wait" for each function call to finish.

The main function is supposed to print the 4 different numbers that are inputted.

I've tried using async-await on my main function, but that had the same result. Is async-await even needed for this?

I'm using the command `node input.js` in terminal to run the program. No HTML.

```
function getInput(question) {
  var readline = require('readline');

  var rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question(question, function (x) {
    var aString = parseInt(x);
    rl.close();
    entered = true;
    return aString;
  });

}

async function main() {
  var i = 0;
  var myGuess;
  while (i <= 3) {
    myGuess = await getInput("Enter something: ");
    console.log(myGuess);
    i++;
  }
}
main();
```

I expect to see:

```
Enter something: 3 // just entering random numbers
3
Enter something: 9
9
Enter something: 12
12
Enter something: 55
55
```

But I get:

```
Enter something: undefined
Enter something: undefined
Enter something: undefined
Enter something: undefined
2222                         // I only got to enter 2...
```

Answer (score 1):

read how to use [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can only be used
>   inside an async function.

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    rl.question(question, function (x) {
      var aString = parseInt(x);
      rl.close();
      entered = true;
      return resolve(aString);
    });
  });
```